# Neo4j is creating multiple nodes and relationships with the same cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I'm trying to dynamically generate cyphers to create nodes and relationships on Neo4j (v3.0.4) but I'm getting some weird results.

I've been working with cypher queries for a while now and I can't see what's wrong with my query here

So I have a Neo4j database with a constraint on unique `id` for `:Individuals`

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Individual) ASSERT i.id IS UNIQUE
```

Given that, I'm running the following cypher query:

```
MERGE (parent:Individual {id:"334717eb182371a126e46d44bde3ef6b"}) 
SET parent.name = "SOME PARENT NAME"
WITH parent 
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent)<-[del:IS_RELATIVE]-(n)

WITH parent, n, del 
DELETE del 
WITH parent 

CREATE (c1:Individual {name:"CHILD 1"}) 
CREATE (parent)<-[r1:IS_RELATIVE {birth:"2017-02-24"}]-(c1) 

CREATE (c2:Individual {name:"CHILD 2"}) 
CREATE (parent)<-[r2:IS_RELATIVE {birth:"2015-01-23"}]-(c2)
```

And the first time I run it, it results me:

```
Added 3 labels, created 3 nodes, set 7 properties, created 2 relationships, statement executed in 1201 ms
```

Which is great! The expected result.
But if I run the **same** query again, it results

```
Added 4 labels, created 4 nodes, set 11 properties, deleted 2 relationships, created 4 relationships, statement executed in 540 ms.
```

And if I run the same query again:

```
Added 8 labels, created 8 nodes, set 21 properties, deleted 4 relationships, created 8 relationships, statement executed in 192 ms.
```

And then

```
Added 16 labels, created 16 nodes, set 41 properties, deleted 8 relationships, created 16 relationships, statement executed in 583 ms.
```

And notice that the first node is not being duplicated, just the "child" ones with their relationships...

I don't know what I'm missing...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the more simple way to fix your query is changing all `CREATE` statements by `MERGE`, like this:

```
MERGE (parent:Individual {id:"334717eb182371a126e46d44bde3ef6b"}) 
SET parent.name = "SOME PARENT NAME"
WITH parent 
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent)<-[del:HAS_CHILDREN]-(n)

WITH parent, n, del 
DELETE del 
WITH parent 

MERGE (c1:Individual {name:"CHILD 1"}) 
MERGE (parent)<-[r1:HAS_CHILDREN {birth:"2017-02-24"}]-(c1) 

MERGE (c2:Individual {name:"CHILD 2"}) 
MERGE (parent)<-[r2:HAS_CHILDREN {birth:"2015-01-23"}]-(c2)
```

This way you can run the above query multiple times and the nodes will not be created again.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work either. Actually, for MERGE to guarantee uniqueness, I'd have to create a constraint on the "name" attribute, and that's not what I want

Comment: @EltonHoffmann, I don't know if I understood your problem completely. According the docs the MERGE clause ensures that a pattern exists in the graph. Either the pattern already exists, or it needs to be created. I ran the query here multiple times and the nodes are not recreated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark it as solved, although the use of MERGE here is not to match previously existing nodes, but to prevent neo4j from running the same script in 2 parallel flows and thus duplicating the nodes

Answer (score 0):

You only have a uniqueness constraint is for the `id` property of `Individual` nodes.

Because there is no uniqueness constraint on the `name` property, your `CREATE (c1:Individual {name: "CHILD x"})` clauses will always create new nodes. You would need to specify a `id` property when you create those nodes in order to see constraint errors whenever you tried to re-use an existing `id`.

Also, you should use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` so that you don't have to deal with errors when the constraint is violated, and so that your query is not aborted.

For example:

```
MERGE (parent:Individual {id:"334717eb182371a126e46d44bde3ef6b"}) 
SET parent.name = "SOME PARENT NAME"
WITH parent 
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent)<-[del:IS_RELATIVE]-()

DELETE del 
WITH parent 

MERGE (c1:Individual {id: "1234567890"})
SET c1.name = "CHILD 1"
CREATE (parent)<-[r1:IS_RELATIVE {birth:"2017-02-24"}]-(c1) 

MERGE (c2:Individual {id: "2345678901"}) 
SET c2.name = "CHILD 2"
CREATE (parent)<-[r2:IS_RELATIVE {birth:"2015-01-23"}]-(c2)
```

In case a child's node already existed (with the same `id`), but it did not have the name you want to assign to it, the above query sets the name in a separate `SET` clause. (If you kept the `name` property in the `MERGE` clause, you would get an error if a node with the same `id` already existed, but it had a different name.)

*NOTE: you probably also need to think about what to do if a child already has `IS_RELATIVE` relationships that are no longer appropriate.*